# Oracle TRANSLATE function not working on ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, translate

I want to use TRANSLATE on my Oracle ORDER BY to sort a column as A,a,B,b...Z,z instead of A-Z, a-z.

If I apply TRANSLATE in my SELECT and then ORDER BY that column it works fine. Coding TRANSLATE on the ORDER BY appears to have no affect.

```
SELECT a1,  
       translate(a1,
                 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz',
                 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') AS sort_col
FROM (SELECT * 
        FROM (SELECT 'A' AS a1 FROM dual UNION 
              SELECT 'a' AS a1 FROM dual UNION
              SELECT 'B' AS a1 FROM dual UNION
              SELECT '#' AS a1 FROM dual UNION
              SELECT '0' AS a1 FROM dual ) )
--ORDER BY 2 
ORDER BY TRANSLATE(1,
                  'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz',
                  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

The output order should be #,0,A,a,B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given the Translate function in your order by statement a column. It's just always translating `1`.

Replace the `1` in your order by with the `a1` column you're trying to sort on.

```
ORDER BY TRANSLATE(a1,
                  'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz',
                  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

Note that if you're just using this for sorting, you can achieve the same thing in a much more readable way with:

```
ORDER BY UPPER(a1), a1
```

Comment: Thanks. I read the syntax as the "column number" on the ORDER BY.

Comment: In hindsight, I see that I got sideways when I first tried this with a UNIONed result set which issued the error on the ORDER BY requesting "column number". After switching to a subselected result, I never changed from column number.  With regard to the UPPER option, this is a simplified example of a mixed-case column that needs to sort upper/lower separately.